# Powershell - Create HashTable from Arrays

Tags: powershell, hashtable

Does a zip function already exist that would combine two equally sized arrays into a HashTable or some inline method?  Or is the only way to build the HashTable in a for loop.

Answer (score 1):

Use

```
$HT=@{};For($i=0;$i -lt $Array1.count;$i++){$HT.Add($Array1[$i],$Array2[$i])}
```

That's all there is to it, that makes a hashtable from two equally sized arrays.

**Edit:** Ok, I was actually working on making the answer more civil, but thank you for doing that for me. I was also going to add links to the MSDN pages for the [Array class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.array(v=vs.110).aspx), and [Hashtable class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.hashtable(v=vs.110).aspx) for reference. I see no constructors or methods on either of those that would accommodate what you are trying to do. I assume that this is because a Hashtable is a keyed dictionary where you can not have duplicate keys, while an array allows for as many duplicates as you could want.

Comment: I didn't mean to ask for anyone to write a function for me.  I was wondering if one already existed.  The answer given was already implied by 'iterate through both arrays to build the hashtable'

Comment: I edited the question so it doesn't sound like I am asking for 'teh codez'

Comment: This isn't the correct site for such questions. Perhaps the Meta site is, I don't know I really don't use it. This site is setup to assist people that have trouble with existing code that they are working on. Maybe if you posted what you're working with, and asked if there is a more elegant way, or more efficient way to do it your question would fall within the guidelines of this site.

Comment: This is the correct site for such questions.  SO is not limited to only production code and is best served when the questions are more generic at get the the core question.  My question was asking for a more elegant way than building a HashTable in a for-loop.  Although I could have calrified that more.

Comment: You are right, the question is fine, though perhaps poorly worded as originally posted (it's better now). I apologize for my poor behavior, it was uncalled for. Hopefully the reference links in my answer can be of some assistance at this point if nothing else.

Answer (score 1):

LINQ comes with the [`Zip()` array extension method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd267698(v=vs.110).aspx) that takes a second collection and a selector function as its argument - you could use that together with the `ToDictionary()` method to do *exactly* what you want.

The problem is that there is no native language support for LINQ in PowerShell.

That means you'll have to write a helper function in `C#`, compile it with the [`Add-Type` cmdlet](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849914.aspx) and then invoke it:

```
# Create C# helper function
$MemberDef = @'
public static Hashtable ZipIt(IEnumerable<object> first, IEnumerable<object> second)
{
    return new Hashtable(first.Zip(second, (k, v) => new { k, v }).ToDictionary(i => i.k, i => i.v));
}
'@

# Compile and add it to the current runtime
$RuntimeTypes = Add-Type -MemberDefinition $MemberDef -Name Zipper -PassThru -UsingNamespace System.Linq,System.Collections,System.Collections.Generic

# Add-Type emits a public type "Zipper" and an private anonymous type (the lambda expression from Zip())
# We're only interested in the "Zipper" class
$Zipper = $RuntimeTypes |Where-Object {$_.Name -eq 'Zipper'}

# Now zip away!
$Array1,$Array2 = @("a","b","c"),@(1,2,3)
$MyHashTable = $Zipper::ZipIt($Array1,$Array2)
```

`$MyHashTable` is now a regular hashtable:

```
PS C:\> $MyHashTable["b"]
2
```